# AdminLTE 3 - larger left navigation menu

Tags: css, adminlte

I need to enlarge the left vertical menu in AdminLTE 3, from the default with of 250px to 350px.
I tried with this CSS:

```
.main-sidebar, .main-sidebar::before {
  width: 350px;
}   
body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .content-wrapper, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-footer,
body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-header {
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

but this leads to a wrong responsive behaviour: when the page is resized, half menu disappears on the left and the content of the page stretch down instead of swiping left.

Is there a way to enlarge left menu size maintaining responsiveness?
Please give example.

Comment: Look for my screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/AX5cZtx

Comment: Thak you, but I can't find the _transition.scss file, I only see the _layout.scss one in inspector (see: https://imgur.com/9aAAFto). In _layout.css I have: https://imgur.com/SqCzR95 Where do I have to set my custom width?

Answer (score 0):

With these settings it seems to work fine:

```
.main-sidebar, .main-sidebar::before {
  width: 350px;
}
body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .content-wrapper, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-footer,
body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-header {
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar, .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar::before {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

I checked in my project (AdminLTE v3.0.5) everything works perfect. You need to insert adminlte.css at the very bottom and do not forget to make a min if you are using the .min version. Everything is great!

Answer (score 0):

There was still a problem - the sidebar left the compressed state when hovering over 250px, as by default. Another line has been added to the code below to solve this problem.

.sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar:hover, .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar.sidebar-focused { width: 400px; }  /*default 250px*/

Comment: Use de code sample format to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

One text looks like this. Insert adminlte.css or adminlte.css.min at the end depending on what you are using. The new width value is 400px, the default is 250px.

```
/*# main-sidebar width increase */
.main-sidebar, .main-sidebar::before {
    width: 400px; /*default 250px*/
}

body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .content-wrapper, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-footer,
body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-header {
margin-left: 400px; /*default 250px*/
}

.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar, .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar::before {
margin-left: 0px;
}

.sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar:hover, .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar.sidebar-focused {
width: 400px; /*default 250px*/
}
```